# Execution of tasks hangs with Task.WaitAll in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I have a class like below

```
public class ImageUploader
{
   ....

   public Task<string> Upload()
   {
      return new Task<string>(
                () =>
                    {
                        ....

                        return UploadedFilePath;
                    }
            );
   }
   ....
}
```

then i'm using it like this

```
var uploadIcon = new ImageUploader();
var uploadLogo = new ImageUploader();

var uploadIconTask = uploadIcon.Upload();
var uploadLogoTask = uploadLogo.Upload();

Task.WaitAll(uploadIconTask, uploadLogoTask); // never returns
```

and Task.WaitAll hangs for ever!

what is the problem?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It hangs because you never started the tasks. So `WaitAll` is waiting for them to *finish*, which they never will because they never started.

If you look at the doco for [Task.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) you will see that [StartNew()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx) is used for the created tasks - this both creates and starts the task.

Comment: For `async`/`await` you should use `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public class ImageUploader
{
    ....

    public Task<string> Upload()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ....

            return UploadedFilePath;
        });
    }
    ....
}
```